# Common code when overriding abstract methods - Design issue

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract

I've got an abstract class like this

```
public abstract Stuff
{
    public abstract void doStuff();
}
```

Several classes are extending Stuff, overriding doStuff(). doStuff() in general performs totally different tasks for each implementation but shares a common part.

Whats the best way to implement this?

I don't want to write someting like:

```
public void doStuff()
{
    doTheCommonPart();
    ...
}
```

in every extending class.

Comment: does it have to be an abstract class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either:

1. Place the common code in a `protected` method in the `Stuff` class and call it from each implementation of `doStuff`; or
2. Add the common code to your abstract `Stuff` class and call another abstract method.

E.g. (1)

```
public abstract Stuff  
{
    public abstract void doStuff();

    protected void commonCode() 
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

or (2)

```
public abstract Stuff
{
    public void doStuff() 
    {
      // Do the common stuff initially...
      // ...

      // Then call the subclass implementation
      doRealStuff();
    }

    public abstract void doRealStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
public abstract Stuff
{
    public abstract void doStuff();

    public void doTheCommonPart() {
      // ...
    }

    // Template method
    public final void doIt() {
      doTheCommonPart();
      doStuff();
    }
}
```

Then, your client classes just have to call the template method `doIt()`. It will execute the common code part, as well as the concrete implementation of the abstract method `doStuff()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define it like this, which is similar to the [template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
public abstract Stuff
{
    public abstract void doSpecificStuff();

    public void doStuff()
    {
        doCommonStuff();
        doSpecificStuff();
    }
}
```